# How to import data from Windows Mobile App into Excel in C#

Tags: visual-studio, excel, windows-mobile, data-transfer

I need to create a Windows Mobile 6.5 app for data entry. Then data needs to end up insside Excel spreadsheet on the PC.

What is the best way to do that? Can anyone send some sample codes just to get me started?

I am developing in Visual Studio 2008.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

First you need to define how will you transfer the information from device to pc (Cradle,Network).

In your app you can write the information as CSV file, the create an PC application to retrieve it from the device, and then import this file to Excel.

Comment: I agree. You'd need to save your data, however you prefer, and transfer that to the PC for importing into Excel.